# ActiveMerchant payment/CC failing when there is a paperclip attachment in order form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activemerchant

I am able to create and order and successfully run it and save it.  I am using an order model and an order_transaction model.  I added a field so that when filling out the order form and subscribing, the user can upload a photo of themselves that will be featured on the site.  The whole process still works fine, except in the case where the user attaches a photo.  When that happens, it just fails the credit card validation.  Take off the attachment, and then it works again just fine.

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification, :card_expires_on, :response
  after_create :log_transaction

  attr_accessible :first_name,
                  :last_name,
                  :address_one,
                  :address_two,
                  :city,
                  :state,
                  :zip,
                  :country,
                  :email,
                  :verify_email,
                  :term,
                  :shirt_color,
                  :shirt_size,
                  :card_type,
                  :card_number,
                  :card_verification,
                  :transactions_attributes,
                  :card_expires_on_month,
                  :card_expires_on_year,
                  :photo


  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { :medium => "320x320>", :thumb => "100x100#" }
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :address_one, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :presence =    > true
  validate :validate_card, :on => :create
  validate :require_shirt_size, :on => :create



  def purchase
    self.response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card)
    errors.add(:base, response.message) unless self.response.success?
    self.response.success?
  end

  def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :type               => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expires_on_month,
      :year               => card_expires_on_year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )
  end

  def price_in_cents
    total = 0

    if term == '1'
      total = 2000
    elsif term == '2'
      total = 3500
    elsif term == '3'
      total = 4500
    end
    unless shirt_color == 'none'
      total += 1599
    end

    total
  end

  def require_shirt_size
    unless shirt_color == 'none'
      if shirt_size == ''
        errors.add(:base, "Shirt Size required if ordering a shirt.")
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def log_transaction
      self.transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => price_in_cents, :response =    > self.response)
    end

    def validate_card

      unless credit_card.valid?
        credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          errors.add(:base, message)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

order_transaction.rb

```
class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :action, :amount, :response

  belongs_to :order
  serialize :params

  def response=(response)
    self.success       = response.success?
    self.authorization = response.authorization
    self.message       = response.message
    self.params        = response.params
  rescue ActiveMerchant::ActiveMerchantError => e
    self.success       = false
    self.authorization = nil
    self.message       = e.message
    self.params        = {}
  end
end
```

orders_controller.rb

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  if @order.valid? && @order.purchase
    render :success and return
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

It's as if somehow, attaching a photo causes it to lose its ability to pass on the credit card data.  I'm not sure where it's losing it, but it is.  It feels like a bug in paperclip.  Anyone had similar issues with uploading files while making a transaction with activemerchant?  It's a fairly simple order type, there's three subscription options.

Even suggestions on how to better test and see what's going on would be very helpful, it's got me pretty stuck right now.

Comment: I had the same kind of issue in an app I had developed a while ago. The problem ended up with me having to process the file upload first, then remove it from the parameters array, and then process the rest of the uploaded form.

Comment: You can try having it output the params array to console after you've finished processing everything, just to make sure the correct information is getting to the end.

Comment: I ended up with a workaround that seemed to work.  Moved the photo field to the very end of the form, after credit card.  Works now.  Not sure why exactly.